# The most efficient sql schema for searching names and lastnames

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I'm creating a list of members on my site, and I want to enable them to look for eachother by first name and last name or either one. The catch is that a user can have several names, like names and then nicknames, also a person can have more than one lastnames, their maiden name and then the lastname after marriage.

Once users fillout their names and last names, each user could have several names and last names, for example There could be a person with 3 names and 2 lastnames -  names: Eleonora, Ela, El and lastnames: Smith, Brown.

Then if someone looks for Ela Brown, Eleonora Brown, Eleonora Smith or any other combination, they should find this person.

My question, is how should I set this all up in sql (mysql) so tha schema and search is efficient and fast? Didn't want to reinvent a wheel so I turned to pros and asking a question here.

Thanks guys

P.S. I guess the standard solution would be to have a user table, fname table, lname table, userfname table with userid and fnameid and userlname table with userid and lnameid, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this and wether or not search would be fast...

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to differentiate between first names and last names?

I would suggest a `Users` Table having `UserID` 
and also some `UsersNames` Table having `UserID` and `Name`, a one-to-many relationship.

If you need, you could also add a `IsLastName` bit to the `UsersNames` table (or just a `LastName` column, but the bit is better imho).... 
But this way you search one table and can easily locate user ID's, plus you don't limit the number of names each user can have.

**EDIT:**
You could easily take your input string and split it out too. So if somebody put in "John Smith" you could search for both or either name simply by splitting the string and using it in the `WHERE` clause using either `OR` or `AND` depending on your intended functionality.

Comment: I need to be able to differenciate between names and lastnames.

Comment: Right, so you add a `IsLastName` column or just a `LastName` column so that your search can easily return which one you have. At the end of the day, it's just a string with a property.

Comment: Expanding upon this you could do `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserNames WHERE UserName.Name IN ('John', 'Smith')) ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UserNames WHERE UserName.Name IN ('John', 'Smith')) DESC` This would give you the ability to order results with the most likely

Comment: @Seph I suppose that's true if you have *exact* matches.

Comment: It would also work with full text searching for partial word matching, but my sql example would give you a priority list matching names. That is it would show "John Smith" then "John Jones" then "Bob Smith" but it would also return "Smith John" at the same rank (or higher) as "John Smith"

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did somethig like this I processed each name into a single column in a NAMES table. All names, first/last/middle. A second table hold a link to the person record in the PERSONS table.

So each NAME field get linked to one or more PERSONS record. If I search for "Scott" I would find the name Scott in the NAMES table, find the links in the NAMES_TO_PERSONS(/PEOPLE?) table and then return all the records for that name. ie: Scott Bruns, John Scott, David Scott Smith.

It worked very well with only a small amount of pre processing.

Comment: But then you would not have been able to search for "John Smith" because it looked for John in lastnames too?

Comment: @user720943: No, you will be able to search. In this model, you would separate `John` and `Smith` first and then query the tables. It would find any `John Smith` and also any `Smith John` (having `Smith` as firstname or nickname and `John` as lastname). The queries will be slightly more complex but you'll have more flexibility in certain cases.

Comment: user720943, you are correct. I forgot to add that we stored each combination of names. So if the name was Scott David Bruns we stored Scott/David/Bruns/Scott David/Scott Bruns/David Bruns. This could be adjusted as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Text searching is what you need - use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). I've used Lucene on several projects and it's truly amazing - not hard to use and ridiculously fast.

Answer (score 0):

If in your data model the users may have multiple but bounded number of name types then the simplest solution would be to create indecies for each column that stores the name type. You would add a field for first name, last name, nickname, maiden name, etc. This model would be more performant than having a one-many names association.

You may also evaluate if there are general search requirements for the rest of the application or if you would like the search to be more flexible. In this case you can look into using a backend indexing process, such as with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or using [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Initially, I would try to avoid this if possible, because it certainly complicates the project.

Comment: I do not understand the first paragraph of you reply, can you please give me an example of what you're telling me?

Comment: OP stipulated that the number of names is not bounded

Comment: So, if I have many but bounded (say 100) number of name types, then the simplest solution is to create 100 fields?  And this model would be more performant?

Comment: 100 fields would be too many to manage in this way and I would instead go for the approach specified by Matthew PK. I only brought up the notion that if the number of different name types is small then creating an additional table could be overkill.